# After installing Windows 10 SDK, why I can't find makeappx.exe

Tags: windows, sdk

After installing Windows 10 SDK, why I can't find makeappx.exe

In the directory of C:\Program Files (x86) \Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\, there is only one folder called XamlDiagnostics and file GenXBF.dll.

In the directory of `C:\Program Files (x86) \Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64`, there is only one file genxbf.dll.

I have repeatedly installed SDK several times, and again got

> The features installed on this computer are up-to-date

What's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found it was in a different location to the one specified in the Microsoft documentation.

I was following the instructions in the documentation for creating an appx from a Microsoft Edge extension, [found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions/guides/packaging/creating-and-testing-extension-packages#preparing-the-submission-folder).

In the documentation, it says makeappx.exe can be found in the following location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64

This was incorrect - I then found [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/msix/package/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool?redirectedfrom=MSDN) which gave the correct path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\[build
>   number]\x64\makeappx.exe

For some reason the file did not turn up in a search for the filename using file explorer search, even though it was there.